# Float Divs With Window Scroll Within a Fixed Section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to scroll 2 div with page scroll in a fixed section. Here is the live URL to test online

[Floating Div's Issue](http://imenudemo2.apphb.com/features-pricing)

[image]

above is the screen shoot of that section. I've tried position fixed and scroll function as well but nothing works for me.

currently i'm on this stage

```css
.main-content {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}

.left-flot-div,
.right-flot-div {
  width: 19%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #000;
  float: left;
}

.left-flot-div {
  margin-right: 1%;
}

.right-flot-div {
  margin-left: 1%;
}

.main-content-center {
  width: 60%;
  height: 1400px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="left-flot-div"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="main-content-center"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="right-flot-div"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

```
$('#ParentContainer').scroll(function() { 
    $('#FixedDiv').css('top', $(this).scrollTop());
});
```

Comment: Post the js you're using also.

Comment: What grid system is it too - bootstrap3 / 4, gridle, etc?  But your problem looks to be you are setting the widths as a percentage for your float divs, yet your grid system should be handling that

Comment: @Pete bootstrap 3

Comment: in the code, i use float, but on live link you can see grid layout

Comment: ..and what **exactly** is the problem. This isn't clear to me.

Comment: @DanielD question is updated with js, i'm trying

Comment: @Paulie_D scrolling is not working

Comment: That jquery is targeting ID's that don't exist in the current html you posted though...

Comment: @DanielD i just changed them, that's why you're seeing different names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I achieve a similar effect by using this code: (Run it in a full screen or bootstrap will do some magic)

```css
/* Note: Try to remove the following lines to see the effect of CSS positioning */
      .affix {
          top: 20px;
          z-index: 9999 !important;
      }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#2196F3;color:#fff;height:200px;">
      <h1>Bootstrap Affix Example</h1>
      <h3>Fixed (sticky) vertical sidenav on scroll</h3>
      <p>Scroll this page to see how the left navigation menu behaves with data-spy="affix".</p>
      <p><strong>The left menu sticks to the page when you have scrolled a specified amount of pixels.</strong></p>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <nav class="col-sm-3">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="205">
            <li class="active"><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="col-sm-6">   
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1><h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1><h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1><h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
          <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
        </div>
        <nav class="col-sm-3">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="205">
            <li class="active"><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I believe that you are somehow overwritting the affix classes and thats why it doesn't work. In any other case, could you post a jsfiddle? Also it could be affecting the case that you are writing the div with the sizes in the same element. I achieve the same effect in your webpage but I am not totally sure until you post a jsfiddle

Comment: 1st is try to add footer with 800px height in this; div's will overlap it

Comment: 2nd is why floating div size is reducing? they should remain with same size

Comment: updated code have some issue, previous was working fine

Comment: In my code adding a footer requires a data-offset-bottom, I just wanted to show that the basic case with top works. 

The reason why your divs collapse is because most likely, they have the same id, so the same styles are being applied to both (probably this is a partial reason), another thing is that you may interfere with your JS code, that's why my code would not work in your example. Are you overwritting something? Please also post your bootstrap version and any other library